# how override bootstrap navbar div on another div in angular

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

i have used two components 1) navbar 2) login in mobile view when i click into menu option not able to see menu options [Please check image for better understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6iry.jpg) i have used bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may forget to trigger toggle function for your menu when you click the menu button. (Also should check element's display property from css.

You may try with add css for your menu element `z-index: 1` or `position:fixed` for your menu.